# Is there a way to move strings around in filenames? (VisualBasic)

Tags: vbscript, ntfs

So my context is that I have a multiple folders FULL of files sorted alphabetically. Now, in the English world there is a pesky little article named "the", which isn't very significant, and throws your auto-sorting off. Now what I WANT to do is move "the" to the end of a filename, but before one of my suffixes (e.g. -01, -02) because multiple files have the same name but are different versions. So something like this:

"The Exemplar Example-01.ex" --> "Exemplar Example, The-01.ex"

So I turned to VisualBasic Script (VBS) and got close to what I wanted by searching Google, but couldn't get what I wanted exactly. Here's my script:

```
private directfold
directfold=InputBox("Please specify a directory path:")
MsgBox("The folder to be 'de-annnoyed' is: " & directfold)

public annoyance
annoyance = "the"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(directfold)

For each file In folder.Files    

If instr(file.name, searchFileName) = 1 Then
    file.name = renameFileTo
```

So at the bottom of the script you may find the "renameFileTo" command is given no argument because I do not want to rename the entire file, I want to "move around" a part of the filename, if that part of the filename matches the "annoyance" string ("the"). So after my long ramble, can anyone offer me any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make the annoyance word include the trailing space so names like "They" or "Theme" etc won't trigger it.

If the delimiter at the end is always `-` and is the only instance of the character in the string, you can use `Replace` to replace the string. Something like this

```
annoyance = "The "
f = "The Exemplar Example-01.ex"
newName = Replace(Replace(f,"-",", " + Trim(annoyance) + "-"),annoyance,"")
```

`newName` will equal `Exemplar Example, The-01.ex`

The inner `Replace` will replace the `-` character according to how you format it, and the outer will replace the annoyance word with nothing. `Trim` will remove the trailing space.

edit:
If you only want to replace one occurrence of the string, use the following:

```
newName = Replace(Replace(f,"-",", " + Trim(annoyance) + "-"),annoyance,"",1,1)
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp) for additional info on the `Replace` function.

Comment: Sorry about some of my minor mistakes. My first draft did have a trailing space.

Comment: Also, I am now realizing I did not give a condition for instr. How would I do that?

Comment: Also, what if the "the" is in the middle of the word. I will clarify I only want the script to remove it if it is at the beginning.

Comment: If you use `Instr = 1` like you have in your example, it will only match if the annoyance is the first word. Edited my answer for only a single replacement.